# Recycler view not updating with dynamic tab layout in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have Recycler view in list income fragment and I want to use the same list income fragment for all my dynamically created tags by updating the data of recycler view according to the tab selected. I have the below code and works fine for the first time and only in first tab it works. When I swipe to 2nd, 3rd and 4th or come back to 1st, it shows empty recycler data. I am struggling with this past 2 days. Help is very much appreciated.

**IncomeListTabsFragment.java**

```
public class IncomeListTabsFragment extends Fragment {
    private TabLayout branchesTabLayout;
    private ViewPager incomeListViewPager;
    private BranchAPIService branchAPIService;
    private List<Branch> branchesList;
    private View view;
    private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    public IncomeListTabsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_income_list_tabs, container, false);

        incomeListViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(incomeListViewPager);

        return view;
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        getBranchesFromAPI();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());       

        for (Branch branch: branchesList) {
            IncomeListFragment incomeListFragment = IncomeListFragment.newInstance(branch.getId());
            viewPagerAdapter.addFrag(incomeListFragment, branch.getName());
        }

        branchesTabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.branchTabLayout);
        branchesTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    }

    private List<Branch> getBranchesFromAPI() {        
        // .......
        return branchesList;
    }

}
```

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

**IncomeListFragment.java**

```
public class IncomeListFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    TabLayout branchesTabLayout;
    ViewPager incomeListViewPager;
    public static final String ARG_BRANCH_ID = "branch_id";
    private BranchAPIService branchAPIService;
    private List<Branch> branchesList;
    private int branchId;

    public IncomeListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        ((IncomeAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter()).onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    public static IncomeListFragment newInstance(int branch_id) {
        IncomeListFragment incomeListFragment = new IncomeListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_BRANCH_ID, branch_id);
        incomeListFragment.setArguments(args);
        return incomeListFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_income_list, container, false);
        branchId = getArguments().getInt(ARG_BRANCH_ID);
        List<IncomeParent> incomeParentTest = ((GlobalVariableHelper) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getIncomeParents();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.income_list_recycler_view);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        IncomeAdapter incomeAdapter = new IncomeAdapter(getActivity(), incomeData());
        incomeAdapter.setParentClickableViewAnimationDefaultDuration();
        incomeAdapter.setParentAndIconExpandOnClick(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(incomeAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    private List<ParentObject> incomeData() {
       //get data for recycler view
        return incomeParentObject;
    }

}
```

Comment: Note: Empty public constructor is not required because it is created by the compiler automatically.

Comment: Yes. It was auto generated one.